# friend function to static member variable with enum class parameter

Tags: c++, enums, static, friend

I have 2 classes in *namespace N*, *class A* and *class B*.
The *class A* has container of *class B*. The *class B* has *struct S* as private static member (settings for every object *B*). The reason being private is that I want accessing this static member through the *class A*.
So I have member function in *class A* which sets private static member of *class B*.
Using `friend class A;` in *class B* works fine however I would like to limit it that only member function of class A *setC* is the friend of the *class B*.
Another thing is that in class A, I have *enum class Type* which helps to set corresponding variables in *struct S*.

How Can I do it using setS as friend function of class B?

note:
I have both classes in separated files for readability and I would like to have it.

Example minimalistic code:

**A.hpp**

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

#include "B.hpp"
#include <vector>

namespace N
{
class B;
class A
{
public:
    enum class Type
    {
        one,
        two,
    };
    A();
    void addValue (int value);
    void printContainer ();
    void setS (Type type, int number);
    void printS ();

private:
    std::vector<B> container;
};

} // namespace N
#endif // A_HPP
```

**B.hpp** - implementation inside to make it simple

```
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

#include "A.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace N
{
class A;
class B
{
public:
    B(int val) :
        value (val)
    {
    }
    // friend class A; this works as it should
    friend void A::setS(A::Type type, int number); // error N::A::Type has not been declared
    void print () {std::cout << "Value: " << value << "\n";}
    static inline void printS () {std::cout << s.first << " | " << s.second << std::endl;}

private:
    struct S
    {
        int first;
        int second;
    };
    static inline S s;
    int value;
};

} // namespace N
#endif // B_HPP
```

**A.cpp** - implementation

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"

namespace N
{
A::A()
{
    // empty ctor
}

void A::setS(Type type, int number)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case Type::one:
            B::s.first = number;
            break;
        case Type::two:
            B::s.second = number;
            break;
    }
}

void A::printS ()
{
    B::printS();
}

void A::addValue (int value)
{
    container.push_back(value);
}

void A::printContainer ()
{
    for (auto& value : container)
    {
        value.print();
    }
}
} // namespace N
```

**main.cpp** just to be complete example

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    N::A a;
    a.setS(N::A::Type::one, 5);
    a.printS();

    a.addValue(1);
    a.addValue(2);
    a.addValue(3);
    a.printContainer();
    std::cout << std::flush;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the headers include each other. So when B.hpp includes A.hpp, the A header guard is already active so the A class members are not visible.

Comment: Yet another problem: `A::Type` – you cannot pre-declare nested types either, C++ simply doesn't support (unfortunately).

Comment: I'd make `setS` a free-standing function, rather than a member function of `A`, as there's no reason it needs to be a member function.  That would de-couple the interdependency (chicken-and-egg problem).  (Seems to be some naming confusion for `setS` and `setC`.)  But since "C++ is designed to protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli." ... maybe just make all of A a friend.  The classes are intimately connected already — I'd put them in the same header file.  Another alternative is make a mutual friend intermediary class that is the go-between.

Comment: Have you noticed that you call the function `setS` in `A` but have a `friend A::setC` within `B`? Of course the names must be the same.

Comment: `#include "B.hpp"` isn't needed in A.hpp (and remove cyclic dependency issue).

Comment: @Eljay Yes, both classes are really connected. I still think to put them in one file but as they will be much large compared to single example, I am not certain if this is best solution. Neverthless thanks for input - the options. Seems that declaring class A as friend of class B is probably the easist solution.

Comment: @Aconcague Thanks for pointing this out, as for creating a simple example, I rename it but not in all places. Corrected in example.

Comment: _Side note:_ Every time I see the enumeration constants `one` and `two`, I cannot get it out of my head that their underlying `int` values are, respectively, `0` and `1`! Lol... Of course, that does not matter for your program; it does not change its functioning in any way.

Comment: I recommend getting it to work initially with `A` and `B` together in one file. That way you can work out all the forward references, cyclic dependencies, and so on. After that, see what it would take split `A` and `B` into separate files.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your case is a cyclic include!

`#include "A.hpp"` provokes, of course, including that one's contents into the current file, which then includes `B.hpp` and that one finally yet another time `A.hpp` – the resulting code from then looks like:

```
ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

ifndef A_HPP   // but it IS defined already, see above!!!
#define A_HPP

// definition of A,
// but NOT active!

#endif

// definition of B, NOT seeing A, as not active

#endif

// active definition of A

#endif
```

You need to break the cyclic include! `B.hpp` *does* rely on `A.hpp`, as you rely on a nested type (I assume you do not want to change…) which you cannot pre-declare, that's not supported by the language (unfortunately). On the other hand you do not need to pre-declare `A` within `B.hpp` – you have the include, don't you (well, didn't work so far, but we are going to fix...)?

`A.hpp`, though, is fine with `B` just being pre-declared (as long as you access the `std::vector` members only within `A.cpp`), so you can – and need to – drop the inclusion of `B.hpp`. Now including both `A.hpp` and `B.hpp` results in:

```
ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

// definition of A

#endif

ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

ifndef A_HPP   // now again defined already
#define A_HPP

// definition of A, not active again, but this time
// it doesn't matter as it's already there above

#endif

// definition of B now seeing A
// (not from its own include but the previous one)

#endif
```